# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}(x^2( 1+2+...........+\left[\frac{1}{|x|}\right]))$, where $[a]$ is the largest integer not greater than $a$, a is real

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

My question is that Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}(x^2( 1+2+...........+\left[\frac{1}{|x|}\right]))$ For any real number a, [a] is the largest integer not greater than a.

My approach :-The series can be written as
 $$a_n=x^2\left(1+2+.......+\left[\frac{1}{|x|}\right]\right)$$
We have one another series 
$$b_n=x^2\left(1+2+..........+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)=x^2\left(\frac{\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right)}{2}\right)$$
$a_n<b_n$
and $\lim_{x\to 0}$ i.e. $\lim_{\frac{1}{x}\to \infty}b_n=\frac{1}{2}$ so:-
$$\lim_{x \to 0}a_n=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Your "closed" formula for $b_n$ makes no sense because $\frac 1 {|x|}$ may very well be a non-integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\frac1{|x|} -1\le \left[ \frac 1{|x|}\right]\le \frac1{|x|}$$

Then apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: So ,answer is $\frac{1}{2}$ as both the series are converging to $\frac{1}{2}$, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  We merely bracketed the answer and applied the squeeze theorem.